# Linear Programming Blending Problem with a Syntax Error

Tags: python, linear-programming, pyomo

in the following linear programming problem I keep getting a syntax error. Does anyone know why this may be? The code looks like it should run just fine the way it is, but for some reason, it won't run.

here is the error:

[Picture of syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K21mL.png)

```
# declare the model
model = ConcreteModel()

# declare decision variables
model.R1 = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals) 
model.R2 = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals) 
model.R3 = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals) 
model.R4 = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals) 
model.M1 = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals) 
model.M2 = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals) 
model.M3 = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals) 
model.M4 = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals) 
model.S1 = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals) 
model.S2 = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals) 
model.S3 = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals) 
model.S4 = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals) 


# declare objective
model.profit = Objective(
                  expr = 8.5*(model.R1 + model.R2 + model.R3 + model.R4) + 9*(model.M1 + model.M2 + model.M4 + model.M4) + 10(model.S1 + model.S2 + model.S3 + model.S4) - 7.10*(model.R1+model.M1+model.S1) - 8.5*(model.R2+model.M2+model.S2) - 7.7*(model.R3+model.M3+model.S3) - 9*(model.R4+model.M4+model.S4, 
                  sense = maximize)

# declare constraints
model.Constraint1 = Constraint(expr = (20*model.R1 + 40*model.R2 + 30*model.R3 + 55*model.R4) >= 25*(model.R1 + model.R2 + model.R3 + model.R4))
model.Constraint2 = Constraint(expr = (20*model.M1 + 40*model.M2 + 30*model.M3 + 55*model.M4) >= 35*(model.M1 + model.M2 + model.M3 + model.M4))
model.Constraint3 = Constraint(expr = (20*model.S1 + 40*model.S2 + 30*model.S3 + 55*model.S4) >= 25*(model.S1 + model.S2 + model.S3 + model.S4))
model.Constraint4 = Constraint(expr = model.R1 + model.R2 + model.R3 + model.R4 == 2000)
model.Constraint5 = Constraint(expr = model.M1 + model.M2 + model.M3 + model.M4 == 1500) 
model.Constraint6 = Constraint(expr = model.S1 + model.S2 + model.S3 + model.S4 == 750)  
model.Constraint7 = Constraint(expr = model.R1 + model.M1 + model.S1 <= 1000)
model.Constraint8 = Constraint(expr = model.R2 + model.M2 + model.S2 <= 1100)
model.Constraint9 = Constraint(expr = model.R3 + model.M3 + model.S3 <= 1200) 
model.Constraint10 = Constraint(expr = model.R4 + model.M4 + model.S4 <= 1100)
```

Comment: Missing an asterisk on 10 in your objective function, and you didn't close a parentheses

Comment: Two things: `10(model.S1 + model.S2 + model.S3 + model.S4)` should be `10 * (model.S1 + model.S2 + model.S3 + model.S4)`, and `9*(model.R4+model.M4+model.S4` is missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: thanks, everyone, sometimes another set of eyes is all it takes!